# MVC Controller not mapping input parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am doing a post request which is correct (I have proven it in the pic below), yet MVC is not mapping it to my model, even though Newtonsoft.Json class is able to map my post data to the same data model without issue. How do I debug this further?

Data to replicate the issue (just tested it and the issue is still present):

Model:

```
public class LsByTag
{
    public int TagId;
    public int PageId;
    public int ItemsOnPage;
}
```

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public int TestOfMapping(LsByTag lsByTag)
{
    return lsByTag.TagId;
}
```

Javascript function to call it:

```
async function MappingTest() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost/WebApp/Ls/TestOfMapping', {
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "credentials": "include",
        "body": JSON.stringify({ TagId: 1, PageId: 2, ItemsOnPage: 3 })
    });
    return response.json();
}
```

[image: MVCNotMappingModel]

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the code for the signature of your Controller method (not a pic). Also, we need to see the code for the request (AJAX, form attributes or whatever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net's model binder can't do it's work because your `LsByTag` class defines `TagId`, `PageId` and `ItemsOnPage` as fields (`public int TagId;`)instead of properties `public int TagId { get; set; }`

Properties have getters/setters backing them generated for you, which are used by the model binder to actually set the values it parses.

To fix, change your model to contain properties e.g.

```
public class LsByTag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public int ItemsOnPage { get; set; }
}
```

This is explained in the [Model Binding docs for complex types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#complex-types)